# Cannot upload file using JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jax-rs

I am trying to add a Rest to my backend for uploading files. I use this code on the server:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;
@POST
@Path("/upload_thesis")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @DefaultValue("true") @FormDataParam("enabled") boolean enabled,
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream file,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDisposition
```

After I have packaged my program as a jar file and put it on the `apache tomcat` server, I see this error on the server:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Wrong or absent annotation at parameter with index 1 at class
```

I use this version of jersey on my dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.29</version>
    </dependency>
```

**EDIT:**

I think I have a dependency problem, I am confused which one I have to use:

```
import com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam;
```

or

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataBodyPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the version of Jersey you are using:

- For Jersey 1.x, use types from `com.sun.jersey`.
- For Jersey 2.x, use types from `org.glassfish.jersey`.

---

When it comes to dependencies, pick the following for Jersey 1.x:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And the following dependency for Jersey 2.x:

```java
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```